# Why did Gradle change my module path from relative to absolute?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I just checked out an Android project a colleague of mine checked in where `gradle.xml` was set up with realtive paths in the `modules` section though the use of `$MODULE_DIR$`. When I built, Gradle changed that path to absolute. Why? How can I make Gradle continue using relative paths? Or should `gradle.xml` not be included in source control? The changes are also reflected to the `.iml` files in IntellIJ, which I presume are generated by Gradle based on `gradle.xml`. Correct?

**Before:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" 
                value="$USER_HOME$/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/SubModule" />
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

**After**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" 
                value="$USER_HOME$/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="C:\coding\source\work\ProjectX" />
            <option value="C:\coding\source\work\ProjectX\SubModule" />
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a related bug in IntelliJ bug tracker : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122893#_ga=1.28638463.2110637748.1360838067

According the [Release notes of AndroidStudio-0.5.8](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio058released) : the fix from jet-brain is now included in AndroidStudio.

So, you(and/or your colleague) probably need to update to AndroidStudio-0.5.8

Just to share my experience : we never commit .iml files, nor any IDE specific files under SCM and especially with Android-Studio : a simple import from the root build.gradle file is enough to have an up-and-running project in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Interesting. Not checking in IML files only goes for Gradle-projects, right? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and not Android Studio, and I see the fix is scheduled for v13.1.3 of IntelliJ. Will get back to this answer and accept if that upgrade fixes the issue.

Comment: I just tested deleting .iml files, expecting them to be regenerated by Gradle when loading the project in IDEA/Android Studio. That did not happen. I suspect your method of not checking in .iml only works because you *do* have an initial check in of those files. Am I right? Also, are you checking in `.idea/gradle.xml` and `.idea/libraries`?

Comment: No. There is absolutly no iml files under SCM... but I'm using gradle-wrapper, so I have gradlew, gradle.bat, directory gradle/ and of course build.gradle and gradle.settings under SCM (but nothing specific to AS)

Comment: I upgraded today to v13.1.3 of IntelliJ, and this solved the issue for me as well.